# feeding large numpy arrays to tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have a large numpy arrays (X) which I can load onto the CPU but it is too big for the GPU/Tensorflow.I would like to perform array operations on X using tensorflow so I break up the array into batches (using numpy), feed it to tensorflow, and then finally concatenate the final output arrays to give me the numpy array Y. I am new to tensorflow so I think there should be a better/faster way to feed in the numpy array.

```
#X is a large numpy array
#batches is an integer which defines the number of batches

X_list = np.array_split(X,batches)

X_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
Y_tf = some_function(X_tf)

for batch in range(batches):
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(init)
    Y_list.append(sess.run(Y_tf, feed_dict={X_tf: X_list[batch]}))
    sess.close()

Y = np.hstack(Y_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the tensorflow [dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) class, as it has capability of handling large np arrays.  As long as the array can fit in memory, it can be loaded and batched however you want.

A basic implementation would look like (more detail [here](https://medium.com/@ntoyonaga/tensorflow-dataset-api-implementation-of-preprocessing-batch-normalization-174d6e0f9905))

```
#load np array X 

#make placeholders for dataset    
X_placeholder = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=X.shape)    

#make data set from placeholders    
dataset = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_placeholder)) 

#batch
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to use the Dataset API but it turns out to be slower than my earlier method. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The placeholder method reduces greatly the speed that the data is feed into the system, even up to 32%. For a more detailed explanation of this I recommend reading this great course notes: [lecture 03](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kMGs68rIHWHifBiqlU3j_2ZkrNj9RquGTe8tJ7eR1sE/edit). The ideal would be not to use placeholders, however, because your dataset is large, you can run into the

> 2GB limit for the tf.GraphDef protocol buffer. [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#consuming_numpy_arrays)